# Convergence in Probability of $X_n = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{(1/n,2/n)}$

Tags: probability-theory

I would like to prove or disprove, that $X_n = \sqrt{n} \mathbb{1}_{(1/n,2/n)}$ will converge in probability. The probability measure used is the lebesgue-measure on $[0,1]$

$X_n$ converges in probability against X **iff** $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon)=0$

These are the approaches I have tried so far:

---

### Application of Chebyshev's Theorem:

$P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\leq \frac{E[|X_n|]}{\epsilon}$ but

$E[X_n]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/n \cdot \sqrt{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/\sqrt{n}$

which is divergent, so the expectation does not exist and didn't give me a clue on its possible convergence in probability.

---

### Estimate against bigger Probability

I tried estimationg: $P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\leq P(|X_n-1/n|>\epsilon+1/n)$ but this lead me to nothing I could work with.

---

I would appreciate help in form of clues on what approach to use or a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it so hard: $P(|X_n| \geq \varepsilon) \leq P(|X_n|>0)=?$

Alternately you can assume WLOG $\varepsilon<1$ and then it isn't even a bound, you just have $P(|X_n| \geq \varepsilon)=P(|X_n|>0)$.

(I assume from context that the probability space is $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, though you should really have specified that or something equivalent to it.)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'll edit it accordingly.

Comment: Even if it's not Lebesgue measure we can bound your value above by $P( (0, 2/n) )$ and use standard convergence results for decreasing sets.